# Django DecimalField not displaying

Tags: django, django-forms, form-fields

For some reason it's not displaying when all the other fields are.

In **forms.py** I have

```
class addonForm(Form):
    choices = [('true','true'),('false','false')]
    name = CharField()
    fixed = ChoiceField(choices=choices)
    depth = DecimalField()
```

In **views.py** I have

```
def myView(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    form = addonForm()
    context.update({'form':form})

    return render_to_response('addonPage.html',context)
```

And in the template **addonPage.html** I have

```
...
{{ form }}
...
```

Yet in my template I only shows the *name* and *fixed* elements in the form. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure that `DecimalField` is being imported from `django.forms`, not `django.models`.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, it was exactly as August Men said. I wasn't explicitly importing the field from django.forms so I guess it was using the django.models version.